# Terraform lambda_function_association for CloudFront as optional list within a module

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

we have our static stack (CloudFront, S3, ..) defined as a configurable module for different projects. Now some of them need edge lambdas and I wanted to make them configurable (and optional(!)), too.

We are using the module as following:

```
module "static" {
..
  lambda_function_associations = [
    {
      event_type = "viewer-request"
      lambda_arn = "${aws_lambda_function.onex_lambda_viewer_req.qualified_arn}"
    },
    {
      event_type = "viewer-response"
      lambda_arn = "${aws_lambda_function.onex_lambda_viewer_res.qualified_arn}"
    },
  ]
 ..
}
```

and the default cache behaviour of CloudFront is defined as the following:

```
default_cache_behavior {
    ..
    lambda_function_association = ["${var.lambda_function_associations}"]
    ..
}
```

and our variable within the module:

```
variable "lambda_function_associations" {
  type        = "list"
  default     = []
}
```

Applying this stack I get:

```
Error: module.static.aws_cloudfront_distribution.web: "default_cache_behavior.0.lambda_function_association.0.event_type": required field is not set



Error: module.static.aws_cloudfront_distribution.web: "default_cache_behavior.0.lambda_function_association.0.lambda_arn": required field is not set
```

Is there no way to make them work optionally? I really dont want to duplicate the whole stack when adding an edge lambda.

Apparently something like this works for lb_health_check configuration blocks:
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/17292#issuecomment-393984861

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @fboulay not yet, this is still in a feature branch and there was currently no time to investigate more.

Answer (score 2):

I recently stumbled upon the same issue. This is caused by a [terraform limitation](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16582), which prevents us from passing dynamic values to a nested block inside a module.

The only workaround I found was duplicating the resource declaration and creating one of the resources based on a condition in the `count` variable (pass a static variable here, e.g. `associate_lambda_function`).

You can find more details and an example in this [gitlab snippet](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1798358)

Comment: Thanks! Using count is of course a workaround to those limitations.